# inheritdoc specific exception using cref

Tags: c#, sandcastle

How to use `<inheritdoc/>` to inherit specific exception from another method. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary
/// </summary>
/// <inheritdoc cref="Method2(int)" select="exception[@cref='CustomException']" />
public int Method1()
{
    return Method2(1);
}

/// <summary>
/// Summary...
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
/// ArgumentException...
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="CustomException">
/// CustomException...
/// </exception>
public int Method2(int count)
{
    // do something
}
```

When I build documentation and open it, there is no exception for Method1. Currently, my workaround is to add `id="CustomException"` to Method2 and use `<inheritdoc cref="Method2(int)" select="exception[@id='CustomException']" />`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc), the syntax using inheritdoc without Sandcastle would be:

```
<inheritdoc cref="Method2(int)" path="/exception[@cref='CustomException']"/>
```

The [Sandcastle documentation](https://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/86453FFB-B978-4A2A-9EB5-70E118CA8073.htm) indicates the `select` attribute has been deprecated as of November 2019 (I know the question dates from before that, but that's the current situation). The equivalent `path` attribute should be used instead:

```
<inheritdoc cref="Method2(int)" path="exception[@cref='CustomException']"/>
```

The main difference between using Sandcastle or not is the forward slash that the xpath value of the `path` attribute starts with.

I have no experience using Sandcastle myself, but I came across this question when searching for an issue myself: it appears as if the `cref` attribute is not fully supported as a selector in the xpath expression of the inheritdoc `path` attribute. Using `path="/exception"` inherits all the exception documentation for me, but when using `path="/exception[@cref='CustomException']"` no exception documentation is inherited, and when negating it with `path="/exception[not(@cref='ArgumentException')]"` all the exception documentation is inherited. I have not been able to find any information about this behavior anywhere; probably because `cref` is an attribute of `inheritdoc` as well...